# How to access specific Dataframe rows with dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to access specific rows within a dataframe and add up these rows. The index spot of the specific rows is saved in a dictionary.

Now I'm trying to access these rows with the dictionary within a for loop to sum up the values.

```
GHG_names = ['CO2', 'CH4', 'N2O']
GHG_gwp = [1.,28.,265.]
GHG = {}

for j,ghg in enumerate(GHG_names):
    GHG[ghg] = {'GWP': GHG_gwp[j], 'B_index':[]}
    for i,e in enumerate(B_Matrix.index):
        if e.find(ghg) != -1:
            GHG[ghg]['B_index'].append(i)
```

with this I get the following dictionary:

```
{'CO2': {'GWP': 1.0, 'B_index': [23, 92, 93, 427, 437, 438]}, 'CH4': {'GWP': 28.0, 'B_index': [24, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 426, 435]}, 'N2O': {'GWP': 265.0, 'B_index': [25, 429]}}
```

I'm trying to access these rows in my matrix:

```
GHG_names = ['CO2', 'CH4', 'N2O']
GHG_gwp = [1.,28.,265.]
GHG = {}

for j,ghg in enumerate(GHG_names):
    GHG[ghg] = {'GWP': GHG_gwp[j], 'B_index':[]}
    for i,e in enumerate(B_Matrix.index):
        if e.find(ghg) != -1:
            GHG[ghg]['B_index'].append(i)
    print(B_Matrix[GHG[ghg]['B_index'], 'Total'])
```

I tried a few different variants, but it's not working.

My goal is to access these index numbers and sum them up for each Greenhouse gas (CO2, CH4, NO2)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean `sum([23, 92, 93, 427, 437, 438]) ` for `CO2` etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access dictionary entries with their keys e.g.

```
print(GHG["CO2"]["B_index"])
#[23, 92, 93, 427, 437, 438]
```

iterate over the list of names to access all entries systematically and sum up their single indices

```
for ghg_name in GHG_names:
    _sum=0
    for idx in (GHG[ghg_name]["B_index"]):
        _sum+=idx
    print(ghg_name, _sum)
```

that gives you the following output:

```
CO2 1510
CH4 1449
N2O 454
```